# JS Promise.all and a combination of failed and successful Apex calls: how to deal with that?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, exception

In the controller of a LWC, we use `Promise.all` to call an Apex method with different inputs. The code for this:

```
const funcs = productCodesBatches.map(productCodesBatch =>
  getSearchResultsBatch( { productCodes: productCodesBatch, oppId: this.oppId } )
);
return Promise.all(funcs);
```

So `getSearchResultsBatch` is the Apex method, it receives a list of product codes and the id of an opportunity and it returns a list of results (prices and stock). It does this by calling an external webservice. Experience has taught us that this webservice performs better when called with small batches in parallel, then with one big batch (5 parallel calls with 50 products are handled much faster than 1 call with 250 products).

Unfortunately, the webservice fails occassionally, returning an HTTP 500 error. Shame on us, up until now these errors were only logged somewhere, but never displayed to the user. The user just got no results at all or not enough results, but never an error message. We want to improve that.

One solution would be to generate an `AuraHandledException` in Apex and handle this in JS. We have done just that with another webservice, which needs to be called only once.

But in case some calls fail and some succeed, we would like to present the results of the succeeded calls, as well as some indication that the results are incomplete. The user could then decide to search anew or just use the presented results.

Generating one `AuraHandledException` will trigger the catch part of the `try-catch` around the `Promise.all`, won't it? And in that catch part we won't have access to the results of the successful calls, will we?

A possible solution would be not to generate an `AuraHandledException`, but to have the Apex method return a generic `List<Object>` and have the JS code inspect that, but that would require big changes (multiple layers are involved).

How do we deal with this?

Comment: I would start with where the issue is which is the apex making the callout. Is there no retry mechanism (2, 3 retries) within the apex that may solve your problem entirely since it only occasional fails? In terms of your UI/JS question - what's the end user going to do if you tell them you got "half-results"? I'd assume their action will be the same regardless if you present an error or incomplete results which is to retry the search.

Comment: Promise.all returns an array of Promises, you would only see errors in the promise(s) that failed. So if 1,2,3 and 5 succeed but 4 fails, you'd just see the error in Promise.all(funcs)[3] i think

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, when it comes to handling both fulfilled or rejected Promises, [Promise.allSettled()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) method may be helpful:

> The `Promise.allSettled()` method returns a promise that resolves after all of the given promises have either `fulfilled` or `rejected`, with an array of objects that each describes the outcome of each promise.
> It is typically used when you have multiple asynchronous tasks that are not dependent on one another to complete successfully, or you'd always like to know the result of each promise.

In your case (if one call was successful and another one failed):

```js
callBatches() {
    const funcs = productCodesBatches.map(productCodesBatch =>
        getSearchResultsBatch( { productCodes: productCodesBatch, oppId: this.oppId } )
    );
    Promise.allSettled(funcs)
        .then((results) => results.forEach((result) => console.log(result.status)));
    //> "fulfilled"
    //> "rejected"
}
```

> **For each** outcome object, a `status` string is present. If the status is `fulfilled`, then a `value` is present. If the `status` is `rejected`, then a `reason` is present. The `value` (or `reason`) reflects what `value` each promise was `fulfilled` (or `rejected`) with.

Comment: This looks promising, thanks! I am wondering though, will raising an exception in the Apex method automatically signal "rejected" to the calling JS function or do I need to do something special to make that happen?

Comment: `Promise.allSettled` method will never reject - it will resolve once all Promises in the array have either rejected or resolved. You need to handle resolved results separately. The result can be eighter `{status:"rejected", reason: [fail reason description]}` or  `{status: "fulfilled", value: [resolved value]}` . This information is enough to handle Promises results.

Comment: So the Apex method should return a String, representing a JSON object?

Comment: No, this step is redundant, the value of the `value` field of success result would be a JS object.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't understand: how does Promise.allSettled detect that the Apex method has failed? What result must the Apex method return, for successful and for failed calls?

Comment: if the Apex controller method throws an exception `Promise.allSetlled` will 'detect' that call as failed. I really recommend you to play around with this method, there is nothing extraordinary.